# Editing an access database in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

So for an exercise at school i have to use an Access database in PHP, but now i have to create an option to be able to edit the data whilst in the PHP file. I've had to make a delete button first, which works now - but this is my next problem. I'm not very good at things like these yet, so i could really use some help.

My code is:`

```
$dbName='REIZEN.mdb';

$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=". realpath($dbName) ."; Uid=; Pwd=;");

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM klanten");

echo ('<table border = "1" style="width=100%">');

foreach ($result as $value){

    echo ('<tr>');

    echo ('<td>');
echo ($value['KLANTNR']);
    echo ('</td>');

    echo ('<td>');
echo ($value['VOORNAAM']);
    echo ('</td>');

    echo ('<td>');
echo ($value['ACHTERNAAM']);
    echo ('</td>');

    echo ('<td>');
echo ($value['ADRES']);
    echo ('</td>');

    echo ('<td>');
echo ($value['POSTCODE']);
    echo ('</td>');

    echo ('<td>');
echo ($value['WOONPLAATS']);
    echo ('</td>');

    echo ('<td>');
echo ($value['PROVINCIE']);
    echo ('</td>');

    echo ('<td>');
echo ($value['TELEFOON']);
    echo ('</td>'); 

echo ('<td>');
    $path = "delete.php";
    echo ('<a href="'. $path.'?id='.$value['KLANTNR'].'">Delete</a>');
    echo ('</td>');

    echo ('</tr>');

    }

    echo ('</table>');

    ?>`
```

Comment: So ask your teacher... If you don't know how to do it ask them to explain. That's what they are there for.

Comment: Are you in school now?

Comment: @Julian Hey i have given solution for delete before some time same way you can try for edit like create link edit,php then using update query it will helps you will learn more this way.

Answer (score 0):

Make for each row an form like `<tr><form>...</form></tr>` 
and put all the data in `<td><input name="KLANTNR"/></td>`'s and add and submit button in each form. 
And then u can update the edited row on server-side. If this didn't help you, better ask your Teacher ;)